# Is there a word for "timeless" that doesn't imply the passage of time?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, time

I know this is really weird, but I think I'm essentially trying to describe Death as an entity that is to a temporal stream of events what a painting is to a film; both are complete entities, but are fundamentally different in how they deal with time. The painting is temporally static, whereas the film has a changeable moment - like life, it has a "present", past and future.

If I try to write about death in this way, is there a word to express that?

Infinite, unchanging, eternal and constant don't quite seem to work because they imply a passage of time around the subject. I'd considered "timeless", but I'm not entirely sure about it because I feel like it has too many connotations of "classic", or again, that it simply implies something unaffected by time rather than something alien to it.

I realise this is a bit of a longshot, but does anyone have any ideas? If there isn't a word for it, I'd even be up for suggestions for a new word, so long as it's meaning is recognisable.

Comment: 'Punctive' is defined:  a punctive event happens at a point, or what can be considered a point, in time. It's usually used when discussing grammar (the synonym 'punctual' is also used, but has a far more common sense) and contrasts with 'durative'.

Comment: Death is a time span with a more or less well defined beginning, so it is not timeless at all. It is *eternal* (at least one sided infinite interval of time).

Comment: Guys, please stop posting answers in comments. It defeats the upvote/downvote system and makes it harder for visitors to find and compare answers.

Comment: I wish you'd give us an idea how you want to use the word, with an example sentence.

Comment: This is a really great question alluding to a very subtle concept. Love it.

Comment: Requests for D-I-Y coinings do not match ELU's mission statement to report accurately on accepted English usage.

Comment: @user1717828 Requests for clarification are quite appropriate as comments. As other comments and the diversity of answers have now shown (and as OP concedes), this is not an easy concept for them to latch on to / get across. Suggesting answers might help OP to clarify their communication.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I get what you're saying, but suggesting an answer is not a request for clarification, but a suggested answer. It should  be posted as an answer and OP can iterate through it in the comments section (of that answer).

Answer (score 30):

The word *atemporal* means

> independent of or unaffected by time.

[(Merriam-Webster's definition)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atemporal)

Comment: Wizard, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!

Comment: @user203511, if it fits your needs, don't forget to mark the answer with the green checkmark

Answer (score 9):

**"eternal"** might be the word you're looking for.

> - **unchanged by time**, esp being true or valid for all time; immutable, eternal truths. [**TFD**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eternal)

Comment: "Infinite, unchanging, **eternal** and constant don't quite seem to work because they imply a passage of time around the subject."

Answer (score 4):

I'm accustomed to using "stasis" for the concept but it makes no sense for a painting. But as for Death itself we don't use such words at all. "Final" is what tends to get used.

Comment: It seems like "static" is the best answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Everlasting. I think it could give the idea of atemporal moment or circumstance. I really cannot think of another word giving the idea disconnected to time; there is a danger to fall into phyilosophical discourses and statements—things I could digress of for hours and hours, but now I do not feel like doing it. Example:

*Duran Duran's song: "Ordinary World" is an everlasting piece of music.*

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you already mentioned the word you are looking for: "static", in the sense of "characterized by a lack of movement, animation, or progression". In the comparison you mentioned, the difference between the painting and a movie is about movement, which is a function of space and time.

Comment: This is more of a comment, if you reach 50 reputation you can comment on a question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the adjective "aorist", also the name of the timeless / unlimited tense of some old Indo-European languages.

from TheFreeDictionary 
1. a verb tense, as in Classical Greek, expressing action, esp. in the past, without further implication as to completion, duration, or repetition.

adj.

2. of or in this tense.

[1575–85; < Greek aóristos unlimited]

Answer (score -1):

Since you're willing to accept a new word so long as its meaning is recognizable, I'll offer one:

> ### exchronous

with the intended meaning of "existing outside of (ex-) a/any period of/point in time (chronous)."

Since it's a neologism (as best I can tell), I have no sources/references to cite for this one.

Comment: How are non-words going to help people looking here for guidance on  acceptable English?

Comment: @Edwin From the OP's question: "If there isn't a word for it, I'd even be up for suggestions for a new word, so long as it's [sic] meaning is recognisable."

The OP specifically stated that a new word is acceptable; I wouldn't have suggested it otherwise. And I think it ticks the box of "recognizable meaning" as I formed the word from two familiar Greek/Latin parts.

Comment: But I'm with @no-hat on this issue: 'I really don't feel comfortable at all with our site becoming a place where people go who want a word invented. While I delight in exciting new words being invented and promulgated, I think we will rapidly lose our reputation as a place where people can get authoritative answers if many answers are not authoritative but just merely inventive. // I'd go further, in fact, and say that a 'word' only comes into existence when a candidate gains a reasonable currency. ELU deals with accepted English usage.

Comment: @Mitch has also stated (scare-quotes mine, as a _neologism_ has recently been recognised as a _word_) << If a question is looking for a 'neologism' ... [it is] off-topic because it is not answerable [in accordance with ELU policy]. >>

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I suppose if we carry on with this, it should move to chat, since this is going beyond the scope of/relevance to this particular question. I partially agree. I'm generally not a fan of trying to make up words to fit an OP's question; however, if the OP specifically asks for a new word or states that one is acceptable, and a good one comes to mind, I see nothing wrong with suggesting one, especially if the answerer makes it clear it's not an "established" word. I suppose we've just got a difference of opinion on this. I do at least appreciate your explanation for the downvote.

Comment: I have now downvoted the question as well. I held off originally, as, until the request for nonstandard English, it is quite acceptable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you intend to downvote any questions on this site in which the OP mentions that they will accept a new word/phrase, you've got a fair amount of work ahead of you. You can start with mine. :)

Comment: I'd need some help. Perhaps you'd volunteer?